# RadioButton with more than text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I'm trying to create a RadioGroup with RadioButtons that have more than text only.
The image below will make things easier to understand.
[image]

I want the RadioButton to be selected when the user clicks somewhere in the layout around it.
I've tried do do somthing lik this:

```
<RadioGroup>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <RadioButton>
        <...other stuff>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

But that didn't work.
Does somebody know how to easily get the requested layout and behaviour? Thanks

**EDIT**:

I forgot to mention that I don't want to use a list. I want all items to be visible because there are maximum three. Also, the container is a ScrollView

Comment: You can use a ListView (which would work as a RadioGroup) with custom items.

Comment: True, but the number of items can change from one to 3 and I don't want it to be in a scrollable view.

Comment: It won't scroll, if it fits vertically.

Answer (score 0):

As  Der Golem said you can use ListView and set it to be in a single choice mode: `list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

But if you need only few layouts you can register Click listener to your layouts and call onClick events on RadioButtons:

```
 bigLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    radioButton.performClick();
                }
            });
```

Hope it will help